# Webpack-cli Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getArguments')

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack-cli

I'm getting this error:

```
[webpack-cli] TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getArguments')
    at WebpackCLI.getBuiltInOptions (/Users/rafa.mora/Sites/sender_id/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js:831:77)
    at makeCommand.options.entry (/Users/rafa.mora/Sites/sender_id/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js:939:33)
    at async WebpackCLI.makeCommand (/Users/rafa.mora/Sites/sender_id/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js:443:31)
    at async loadCommandByName (/Users/rafa.mora/Sites/sender_id/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js:937:17)
    at async Command.<anonymous> (/Users/rafa.mora/Sites/sender_id/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js:1336:17)
    at async Command.parseAsync (/Users/rafa.mora/Sites/sender_id/node_modules/commander/lib/command.js:935:5)
    at async WebpackCLI.run (/Users/rafa.mora/Sites/sender_id/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js:1360:9)
    at async runCLI (/Users/rafa.mora/Sites/sender_id/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/bootstrap.js:9:9)
```

when running:

```
bin/rails assets:precompile
```

`npx webpack-cli info` output:

```
npx webpack-cli info                                                                                                                                    1 ✘  4s  ruby-3.0.5   14:58:37

  System:
    OS: macOS 13.5
    CPU: (16) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-9880H CPU @ 2.30GHz
    Memory: 1.45 GB / 32.00 GB
  Binaries:
    Node: 16.14.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.19 - ~/Sites/sender_id/node_modules/.bin/yarn
    npm: 8.3.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/bin/npm
  Browsers:
    Brave Browser: 97.1.34.81
    Chrome: 115.0.5790.170
    Edge: 114.0.1823.51
    Firefox: 112.0.2
    Safari: 16.6
  Packages:
    eslint-import-resolver-webpack: ^0.13.4 => 0.13.4
    webpack-cli: ^5.1.4 => 5.1.4
    webpack-dev-server: ^4 => 4.15.1
```

Additional context:

```
"webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
"webpack-dev-server": "^4",
"@rails/webpacker": "5.4.4"
```